# Graceful way to make tables act like values when __indexed?

Tags: oop, inheritance, lua

I'm having this particular problem with my homebrew OO design:

```
Entity = {}
function Entity:new(o)
  o = o or {}
  return setmetatable(o, {__index = Entity})
end
function Entity:init() end
function Entity:think() end
function Entity:spawn()
  --put in entity pool and begin drawing/logic
  self:init()
end

Block = Entity:new{
  x = 0,
  y = 0,
  color = {255, 255, 255, 255},
}
function Block:getPos()
  return self.x, self.y
end
--setPos, getColor, setColor etc
function Block:init()
  self:setColor(math.random(255), math.random(255), math.random(255))
end

a = Block:new()
a:spawn() --a new block with a random color
--a few seconds later...
b = Block:new()
b:spawn() --all blocks change to new color
```

The `color` table is being shared by all prototypes and instances. How can I make that table behave like, say, a string:

```
a = {table}
b = a
print(b[1]) -->table
a[1] = "object"
print(a[1], b[1]) -->object, table
```

As opposed to an object:

```
a = {table}
b = a
print(b[1]) -->table
a[1] = "object"
print(a[1], b[1]) -->object, object
```

**TL;DR: I need to make a new datatype.**

Comment: Create the `color` table in `:new()` instead of statically in the call to `:new()`?

Comment: I'd prefer something a little more flexible

Comment: What do you mean by "a little more flexible"?

Comment: I'd argue that creating instance properties in the constructor is about as "flexible" as you can get and anything else is strictly less flexible but *shrug*. Zupoman covered the available options in their answer.

Comment: Implement `Block:setColor(r,g,b)` by creating new array `self.color={r,g,b,self.color[4]}` instead of assignment of new values to `color[1]`, `color[2]` and `color[3]`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You're right. Could you make your comment an answer? Or can I include it in mine?

Comment: @Zupoman - Of course, you can improve your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to fix your problem:

1. Initialize the `Entity.color` table during `Entity` object initialization – put it in `Entity:new()` function.
2. Replace the `Entity.color` table with four variables that will represent its contents – `Entity.colorred`, `Entity.colorgreen`, `Entity.colorblue`, `Entity.coloralpha`.
3. Make `Entity:setColor()` create a new `self.color` table with new values, instead of modifying the values directly. `self.color = {red, green, blue, alpha}` instead of `self.color[1] = red; self.color[2] = green; self.color[3] = blue; self.color[4] = alpha`.

Comment: @EtanReisner you are right, I guess the third option could be merged into first.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make that table behave like, say, a string:

Your example involves changing Lua variable assignment to copying *values* rather than references. Even if you *could* affect such a change in Lua (you can't) it would be an unspeakably terrible idea.

> The color table is being shared by all prototypes and instances.

Becase you put it in the prototype (e.g. the "class"), so it's equivalent to a static member in an OOP language, shared by all instances. If you want it to be an instance variable, then it needs to be part of *instance* construction, not *class* construction. You need to do the same for `x` and `y` as well, or they'll also be shared by all `Block` instances.

```
function Block:new()
  local instance = { x = 0, y = 0 }
  instance:setColor(math.random(255), math.random(255), math.random(255))
  return setmetatable(instance, {__index = self})
end
```

There are enhancements you can make to the constructor, such as passing in parameters (e.g. to initialize `x`, `y`, etc.), but the important part is that the instance carries its own state.

---

Having `Entity:spawn` simply call init on itself makes no sense. The example code you show suggests it should actually be spawning new instances, but the implementation does not do that.